# within proc sql replace string of a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

Within Proc SQL, I'd like to use a macro variable `&condition3`, but I'd like to replace the string “t1” with “t6” in the macro variable. How can I make the following formula work: `translate(&condition3,'T6','T1')`?

By the way, `&condition3` resolves to: `and t1.store in ('1234')`

The full query:

```
Proc sql;
  Create table xxx as
    Select....
      From ...
      Where condition1
        And condition 2
        &condition3
```

Comment: Joe, Thank you very much for your prompt reply! 
in the log:
&condition3 resolves to: and T1.STR_SITE_NUM in ("1542")  
but in %sysfunc it resolves to: and T6.STR_SITE_NUM in ("6542")
Do you know why 1542 resolves to 6542?

and it won't work directly like that, I have to put %sysfunc(translate(&condition3,t6,t1)) in a macro after condition2. 

Thanks again! and I will try your macro example later.

Comment: Because 'translate' isn't right... will update answer.  In the future please comment on answers if your comment is specific to the answer.

Comment: @Joe I'd like to try your macro example there, but how can I convert my macro variable please? I got the code below from internet originally. 'Str' is user prompt input. <br/> <code>%global STR_COUNT STR;
%let STR_WHERE_CLAUSE=;
data _null_;
/*Data whereclause;*/
if missing(symget('str'))=0 then
do;
length STR_LIST $1000; 
STR1=symget('STR');
STR2=put(input(STR1,best4.),z4.);
STR_LIST=quote(STR2);
 put STR_LIST;
  end;
if missing(STR_LIST)=0 then
call symputx('STR_WHERE_CLAUSE',cats(' and T1.STR_SITE_NUM in (',STR_LIST,')'));
run;
%PUT &STR_Where_Clause;

Comment: @Joe I opened another question thread at below link. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852859/sas-convert-a-marcro-variables-into-macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the `%SYSFUNC` macro statement.

```
%sysfunc(tranwrd(&condition3,t1,t6))
```

You can use that directly , ie without assigning it to another macro variable.  The fact that you're using this in PROC SQL is irrelevant, as you are just creating text to be passed to (anything).

That said, you may want to consider using a macro here instead of a macro variable; this would be more logical if it was

```
%macro condition3(table=);
  and &table..store in ('1234')
%mend condition3;
```

then you can use the macro in SQL just like the macro variable.

```
where condition1
  and condition2
  %condition3(table=t6)
```

Comment: Updated.  Please note the reversal of the arguments: `Translate` has `to, from` and `tranwrd` has `from, to`.

Comment: I believe I'm using the right Translate, because &condition4 and 5 works out the way I want. it's just the number ("1542") somehow changed to ("6542"). any thoughts on that?

Comment: Because you're using the wrong translate.  `TRANSLATE` turns any of the characters in the first list to the corresponding character in the second list.  `TRANWRD` requires _all_ of the characters, all in that order.  So `translate(var,'t6','t1')` turns all 1s into 6s and all ts into ts.  `tranwrd(var,'t1','t6')` turns all `t1` into `t6` only.